# Using CMake to create an executable that can run independently on other machines

Tags: c++, cmake

I’m using LibTorch and OpenCV for a program in Cpp. The compilation and building is done on Linux using CMake. The program builds and runs as expected.

I want to use the executable that CMake created on another Linux machine.
The problem is that I don’t want to install either LibTorch nor OpenCV on the other machine. I’d rather supply the user with a single executable if possible.

How can CMake create a single independent executable?
If making just a single file is irrelevant, how can CMake copy all needed libraries to a single directory?

The current CMake file:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
    project(prediction)
    list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH “libtorch”) # the folder where libtorch in found
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

    find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
    find_package( Torch REQUIRED )

    if(NOT Torch_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR “Pytorch Not Found!”)
    endif(NOT Torch_FOUND)

    message(STATUS “Pytorch status:”)
    message(STATUS " libraries: ${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")

    message(STATUS “OpenCV library status:”)
    message(STATUS " version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
    message(STATUS " libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
    message(STATUS " include path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

    file(GLOB SOURCES ".h" ".cpp") # Link all headers and sources in root dir

    include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
    add_executable(entrypoint ${SOURCES})
    target_link_libraries(entrypoint ${TORCH_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
    set_property(TARGET entrypoint PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

####### EDIT

Thanks for the answers. 
Following Phesho_T answer bellow, I got the static compilation of LibTorch, but it won't compile with the set() instruction. It throws C10_LIBRARY NOTFOUND.

I think I'll try to use the shared libraries. How can CMake be instructed to copy the releveant shared libraries to the "build" folder, so I can pack everything in a .zip file and send it to the user.

Comment: Shipping shared libraries for modules you don't build/maintain yourself is generally a bad idea. They might depend on other shared libraries, these might depend on others and so on - you can't ship all dependencies to your end-user or guarantee that they will have required packages installed.

Comment: Got it. So in order the run the executable on another machine:
1. Install the LibTorch and OpenCV libraries on the other machine.
2. Run the CMake again.
Correct?

Comment: after you've built the application on machine A, you can just copy the executable on machine B which already has LibTorch and OpenCV installed and you can run it without running CMake again assuming: 1) A and B are using the same instruction set (i.e. x86) and 2) they have either the same version of the two libraries, or they two different versions are API and ABI compatible.

Comment: @Pesho_T Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like another answer said, you need to link the static libs of Torch and OpenCV in your executable.

There are a few pre-requisites for this:

1. The two libraries need to have static (.a) libraries installed on your system. If they don't, you may have to manually build them. Steps for this differ between different packages.
2. You need to tell CMake to search for the static libraries *ONLY*. This is done via the [CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES.html) variable. The chances are the default for this is `.so;.a`, meaning it will find the shared library first.

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a")
```

The fact that you're using variables in your `target_link_libraries` command, instead of [imported libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries) (the modern CMake way) makes me think that this should be enough - these variables should expand to full paths to the static libraries, which should then be added to your linker command.

Things are a bit more complicated to explain if imported targets were used, but this might be out-of-scope for this question.

Try it out and let us know how you get on.

Comment: "Things are a bit more complicated to explain if imported targets were used" - If find is configured to prefer static libraries over shared ones, then it is true for both imported targets and variables. Moreover, if `FindXXX.cmake` script provides both variables and imported targets, the variables are usually expanded to the names of imported targets. "The chances are the default for this is `.so.a`" - You probably mean `.so;.a`: this is a **string representation of the array**, containing `.so` and `.a` elements.

Comment: @Tsyvarev in my sandbox, `add_library` won't work with IMPORTED option unless you specify a library type. What if the module was not configured to provide the correct type? Or, for example, you used SHARED and provided an IMPORT_LOCATION pointing to a static library? Re: the default, yep that is right - I mistyped. Will fix.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I edited the original post.

Answer (score 1):

To create a single executable you need to statically link the dependencies into your executable. Check your libraries to see if they provide static-libs else you need to recompile libtorch or opencv to make static libraries.

Comment: First Thanks for the answer.

I have the .so of both libraries. 
How can I do the static link?

Comment: @Arbok .so files are shared libraries. check if there are .a files in your libraries.